# CasperJS : assertHttpStatus() : 301 works with slimer, not with phantom

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, http-status-codes, slimerjs

How do you check if there is a redirection with casper (+phantom) ? Try it :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* check 301 : ***********', function(test){
    casper.start('http://www.linternaute.com/ville/rennes2/ville-35238', function(response){
        this.test.assertHttpStatus(301);    
    })
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
});
```

It works with casper+slimer but not with casper+phantom.

`curl -i http://www.linternaute.com/ville/rennes2/ville-35238`

output : `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`

output casper+slimer : `PASS HTTP status code is: 301`

output casper+phantom : `FAIL #current: 200, #expected: 301` -> issue?

[Differences slimer/phantom](http://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/differences-with-phantomjs.html) -> <kbd>When PhantomJS receives a redirection as HTTP response, it doesn’t call the onResponseReceive with the start status,slimerJS calls it</kbd>

Comment: Does this mean that you have to wait with slimer until the redirect is resolved? As I unterstand, since the `start` callback is returned, the status should be 200. So I would see an issue with slimer.

Comment: I think it should just return the http status code of the url, so `301`. Otherwise how could we test if there is a redirection; if we only get the final status code -after redirection-? It's strange because it works for them : [Redirection_301](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/W0BsRe_i6aI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for more information see [Redirects not followed #442](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/442), if you still want to test 301, here a solution :

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    if(resource.url === 'http://www.linternaute.com/ville/rennes2/ville-35238'){
        this.test.assertEquals(301, resource.status);
    };
});
```

But I finally chose to test redirection in this manner (easier) :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* check 301 : ***********', 1, function(test){
    casper.start('http://www.linternaute.com/ville/rennes2/ville-35238', function() {
        this.test.assertEquals(this.getCurrentUrl(), 'http://www.linternaute.com/ville/rennes/ville-35238');
    })
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
});
```

I just check the current URL correspond to my redirection... An object with properties 'openUrl' and 'urlRedirected' and it's okay -in a loop-...